# Spliting an image dataset

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, split

I have an image dataset (folder of jpg images) .I would like to split it : 70 % for train and 30% for test randomly.

So I write this simple script:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
path = ".\dataset"
output_split=train_test_split(path,path,test_size=0.2)
```

But I don't find anything in folder "output_split"
So where I store output of spliting (train and test)?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using tf.dataset in your project. You can reference this link here for documentation:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory
And this link for a example of the function use:
https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/
Please remember to use the same seed for both training and (testing/validation).
Please note that no changes will happen to your files in your local.